# Magento - issue with customer registration

Tags: magento, registration

I have a question regarding customer registration process with Magento.
I disabled guest .
So you have to register to create an order.

But I just realized something strange.
when you are in your cart, then you want to place ther order, the ordering process starts.
it asks you to register, so you provide all information (name, address etc).
Then you select shipment, payment, then you can validate the order, but if you go back to the catalog before validazion, to add a product for instance, then your registration info islost!
It asks you again to register so you can validate the order.
The information is not maintained in the session…

Is it a bug?
or the normal behavior?
a bug with my new template?

This is a serious issue for my customer, as clients may leave the web site becasue they don’t want to provide twice the info.

Thanks,
Rod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard out of the box behavior, because you are treated as a guest until you actually place the order and customer is created with the inserted addresses. You can change that behavior in couple of ways:

1. Force customer to register before starting the actual checkout

   ```
   // Redirecting customer to login page and back once registered / logged in 
   if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {     
     Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('/*/', array('_secure'=>true))); 
     $this->_redirect('customer/account/login'); 
     return;
   }
   ```
2. Temporary save that info and re-load it in such use-case
3. Alert customers that their data will be lost if they're trying to leave the checkout process somewhere in the middle.

All of those options need some kind of custom module to be build.

Comment: thanks, jernej.
But it's strange.
The cart is saved in a session right? 
I do not loose my products information (list of products).

So why magento does not do the same, and store the information I started to provide in the ordering process?
It makes sense right?

Anyway, it's the way it is :-(
I think the best option might be that when I click on "next" after providing my account info in the form, I update the code in order to create the customer account, and start automatically the player session.

Comment: I will debug the code to see how I can create the customer account based on the customer info provided in the form. 


I am also ready to buy a module if it exists.



if someone knows that, thanks for sharing :-)


Actually, not being the best, but the faster to implement might be to redirect the user to the standard registration/login form when I detect that the user has not started any registered session AND he clickes on the button to start the ordering process from the cart page. This is your first option.

Comment: I will investigate how I can detect whether the user has authenticated, and how to redirect him to the register/login page.

Thanks,
Rod

Comment: @Jernej, on your option number 1, what checkout event did you mean for that code to go?